# Visual Basic Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im working on a program and I get this "Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'."

heres the code that gets this error:

```
Label4.Text = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Backup)
```

And heres the string

```
Dim Backup As String
        Backup = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.MineRbu"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Backup)` returns an array of strings.

**You probably need to change it to this:**

```
'This will insert each value returned from GetDirectories'
For Each Dir as String in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Backup)
  Label4.text &= Dir & VbCrLF
Next

'Alternatively, if you just need the first result:'
Label4.text = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(0)
```

**References**

- [GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The [`GetDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) method returns an array of strings. You're setting that to a string property (`.Text`).

Try this instead:

```
Dim dirs() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Backup)
Label4.Text = string.Join(vbCrLf, dirs)
```

This will extract all the directories into an array, then put each item onto your label (separated by a new line).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare Backup as DirectoryInfo not of type string

Dim Backup As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(path)

see Microsoft [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325.aspx#Y1096)